# Dialogflow Prefers System Entities to User Defined

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have a Dialogflow Agent which will give directions to different venues (rooms on a University campus). I have defined a "venue" entity which is pre-populated with the names of all the various venues.

For the most part, this works fine. If I ask a question like "How do I get to the Beyer Building", it spots the intent and the venue entity ("Beyer Building").

However, if the venue name includes a number or a person's name (e.g. "How do I get to Alan Turing G.107") it fails to spot the entity (even though "Alan Turing G.107" is one of my pre-defined entity values).

Instead, it spots two system defined entities:

- @sys.given-name = "Alan"
- @sys.number = "107"

When it should instead be spotting:

- @venueName = "Alan Turing G.107"

Once I have trained it on a specific example, it works going forward... but there are hundreds of possible values to train. Surely Dialogflow should spot the predefined entity names?

Is there any way I can make it "prefer" my user defined entities instead of system defined entities?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the cases where Dialogflows default approach works quite poorly and a better solution actually exists, but is actively discouraged.

Training phrases come in two modes: [Example mode and template mode](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/training-phrases#example_and_template_modes). Example mode is the default and seems to be what you have been using. With it you specify complete training phrases exactly like the user would say them (`"how can i get to the beyer building"`). Dialogflow then tries to parse and annotate the entities, whereby it does indeed prefer its system entities.

However, you can get around this by specifying the phrases in template mode. With it you include the entity type in the phrase (`"how can i get to @venue:venue"`) and thus avoid Dialogflows automatic annotation.

The only problem with this is that template mode is actually deprecated and doesn't even seem to be available via the console anymore (it does still work via the API).

Technically you don't actually need the template mode, you can do the exact same thing that Dialogflow does automatically in example mode manually by sending your phrases as [`TrainingPhrase`](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents#TrainingPhrase) objects via the API. For that however you would have to parse every single one of your phrases into an array of parts that separates the entities from the rest of the speech. If you do that, do not forget to add spaces between the parts, because Dialogflow doesn't do that automatically.

Why they are doing it that way is a mystery. Entity annotation is an entirely different service from the intent matching and should be optional. Is it because they like getting all this user-annotated data? Who knows, but it's making the development of high quality Google Assistant apps way more difficult than it would have to be.